# Webservice in 8080

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, webserver, glassfish

I am running a GlassFish Server (in Microsoft Windows Server 2008) and deployed a application and configured HTTP to listen on 8080 port. This setup is working in browser as I could able to open the application using the following [link](http://122.165.14.207:8080/HDMSRemote/OnlinePatchUpload?tester) but when I check over online tool to check whether port in opened. Failed where all the online tools show port closed also when I tried to connect using my embedded ARM Device using SOAP protocol it is not working, but other than 8080 port others where workig fie with same OS.

Also the same application is working fine in Windows XP, 7, 8 and 10. but only the problem is in Windows server 2008.

[image: Screenshot]

Firewall is turned OFF and also changed inbound and outbound settings.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Have you forwarded the port of your router/firewall so that it points to your Server 2008 IP on your LAN?

Comment: @root PORT is not opening when tried from client but working when using browser

Comment: In admin portal of Glassfish the port and IP is set, Also in Firewall inbound and outbound to the port is set to accept(tried by turning it off also). Can you pls elaborate what else I can do...???

Answer (score 0):

As I recall with windows server 2008 if you turn the windows firewall off it blocks all inbound, try leaving it on with a specific port exception added.

Comment: tried that also. still same, but 8181 port is showing opened not 8080